# Bash Script using Grep to search for a pattern in a file

Tags: bash, unix, grep

I am writing a bash script to search for a pattern in a file using GREP. I am clueless for why it isnt working. This is the program

```
echo "Enter file name...";
read fname;
echo "Enter the search pattern";
read pattern
if [ -f $fname ]; then
    result=`grep -i '$pattern' $fname`
    echo $result;
fi
```

Or is there different approach to do this ?

Thanks

---

(contents of file)

```
Welcome to UNIX
The shell is a command programming language that provides an interface to the UNIX operating system.
The shell can modify the environment in which commands run.
Simple UNIX commands consist of one or more words separated by blanks. 
Most commands produce output on the standard output that is initially connected to the terminal. This output may be sent to a file by writing.
The standard output of one UNIX command may be connected to the standard input of another UNIX Command by writing the `pipe' operator, indicated by |
```

(pattern)

```
`UNIX` or `unix`
```

Comment: grep should be piped afaik, so doing `ls -l | grep '^d'` for instance will return all the directories in the current location...

Comment: grep will work from a list of filenames, or a wildcard.  It doesn't have to be piped.

Comment: Does your pattern include characters that need to be escaped?

Comment: You also need to show use (1) the contents of the file you're grepping; and (2) the pattern you're entering.

Comment: If your pattern contains special characters use `grep -F` in order to disable them.

Comment: Is this script just for learning purposes, or are you actually going to use this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The single quotes around `$pattern` in the grep statement make the shell not resolve the shell variable so you should use double quotes.

Comment: tried this, but its displaying me only last 2 lines. The file contains 5 lines and the

Comment: as paxdiablo said, please post the content of the file and your $pattern.

Answer (score 8):

Only one of those semicolons is necessary (the one before `then`), but I usually omit it and put `then` on a line by itself. You should put double quotes around the variable that you're echoing and around the variable holding your `grep` pattern. Variables that hold filenames should be quoted, also. You can have `read` display your prompt. You should use `$()` instead of backticks.

```
read -p "Enter file name..." fname
read -p "Enter the search pattern" pattern
if [ -f "$fname" ]
then
    result=$(grep -i "$pattern" "$fname")
    echo "$result"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
read -p "Enter file name..." fname
read -p "Enter the search pattern" pattern
if [ -f "$fname" ]
then
    result=$(grep -i -v -e $pattern -e "$fname")
    echo "$result"
fi
```

Comment: Can you explain why this is a solution, instead of just putting in the code? Can you explain the difference with other answers?

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate in addition to help solve the problem.